# Tell Puppeteer to open Chrome tab instead of window

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

If I have an existing Google Chrome window open, I'd like to tell puppeteer to open a new tab instead of opening a new window. Is there a way to do that? is there some option or flag I can pass to puppeteer to accomplish this?

I have:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function () {

  const b = await puppeteer.launch({
    devtools: true,
    openInExistingWindow: true /// ? something like this?
  });

  const page = await b.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');

})();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```js
const browser = puppeteer.launch();
const page = browser.newPage();
```

This will open a new tab (Puppeteer calls them "pages") in your current browser instance. You can check out the `Page` class docs [here](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page/) and the `Browser` class docs [here](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.browser/).

Comment: Anyway to switch between tabs easily?

Comment: You could use `browser.pages()` to get a list of all the open pages, then use the one you need as `pageFromTheList.doSomething()`

Comment: Please have all the required code in answer. Now you didnt specify where does browser come from? Is it package? If yes where is it?

Comment: Not working :/ in Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit), It still opens up new instance of chrome and it has no history whatsoever, I had to open it along with my other chrome tabs.

 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
 const pptr = require('puppeteer-core');
 (async () => {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
  });

 })(); 

Here I also tried puppeteer-core , means pptr variable await pptr.launch in above variable, still not working. The issues is not closed!

Comment: Hi @PratikCJoshi I've just update the code snippet and links to the docs to reflect where `browser` is coming from. I'm still using this approach successfully in newer versions without problem. 
The official documentation still declare this as a correct way to handle multiple tabs. Your problem may be relate to the chrome binary that you're trying to use. I'll suggest opening a new question and providing more information for your specific case.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use:

`/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --remote-debugging-port=9220`

to get the websocket connection for debugging which then can be fed to Puppeteer:

`await puppeteer.connect({browserWSEndpoint: chromeWebsocket})`

Comment: How do I set this as the default behavior when I want to open Chrome from now on?

My man. Thank you for this. I had a fix on Windows for this, but didn't know how to do it in Linux
Last time I wrote a bot with Puppeteer, I was still using Windows

Where do I buy you a beer?