# Tell Nodejs Puppeteer to open tab in Chrome but not in Vscode

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm studying how to use Puppeteer and I'm struggling to make it open a new tab in my Google Chrome instead of opening new window of VScode.

I found out an answer for a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218584/tell-puppeteer-to-open-chrome-tab-instead-of-window) but it does not work for me.
I tried some solution like set **executablePath** or **usrDataDir** but it did not work.

I also found out an answer [about chagning usrDataDir](https://www.hellojava.com/a/70446.html). But it did not work.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox'], headless: false, executablePath: '/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome'})

const page=await browser.newPage();
```

Anyone know how to do it? Thank you.
Furthermore, I'm using puppeteer-core.

Comment: Can you add your code about userDataDir? I see it's misspelled.

Comment: Please see my given link

Comment: The link already shares some answer, but it doesn't tell me what exact code you tried. Kindly please share your latest code and information about your operating system.